# Just sitting around

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

What are the alternate ways of telling a person that I am doing nothing in the moment? I have tried using 'just sitting around'.

Comment: Idiomatically, *[I'm] **just hangin' / hanging** [out, about, around]* is increasingly common among younger speakers. Or more extreme, ***just vegging*** (mindlessly *vegetating*).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a definitive way of saying this that I can think of. To my knowledge most ways of expressing that you're not doing anything in particular right now are idiomatic.

With that said here are a few idioms that you could use if you want to vary your vocabulary a little:

- Just chillin'
- Nothing much
- Hanging out
- Twiddling my thumbs
- Nothing in particular

There are loads of ways to express this, these are one's I'd use.